# how to use javascript insert xml string to xml node

Tags: javascript, xml

how to use javascript insert xml string to xml node?

like in html use as shown below

```
 element.innerHTML ="abc<p>content</p>";
```

the node.textContent function only set the pure text to the node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `document.importNode` function..

see this ref: [import node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode)

give your full code to give more picture about what you are trying to do :)